# Device is created when sending measures to non existing device - IoTAgent-UL

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We've discovered a bug in the IoT Agent Ultralight.

If we try to send a measure to a non existing device, we'll get a `404 - DEVICE_NOT_FOUND` error but at the same time a device without any attribute will be created in IoTA's and Orion CB's database.

When I say a device without any attribute I refer to the following:

```
{
    "device_id": "test",
    "service": "MyService",
    "service_path": "/MyServicePath",
    "entity_name": "MyEntity:test",
    "entity_type": "MyEntity",
    "attributes": [],
    "lazy": [],
    "commands": [],
    "static_attributes": []
}
```

This is a very important bug, because it's really simple to create as many devices as someone wants and that could eat our database space.

Does someone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

- Which version of IotAgent-ul and external components, I mean, (Fiware OCB and MongoDB) are you using? It's highly recommend to use the latest one.
- It's a good way to run OCB and MongoDB using docker images
- Could you provided us your commands/code that you used to send a meassure?

From my self, I tested it and it works great:

**Curl commands used to send a meassure:**

```
#!/usr/local/bin
mosquitto_pub -t /TEF/sensor03/attrs -m 't|45|c|extreme'
```

**Response from IotAgent-ul:**

```
    {"op":"IOTAUL.Executable","time":"2018-09-21T09:59:17.906Z","lvl":"INFO","msg":"Ultralight 2.0 IoT Agent started"}
time=2018-09-21T09:59:32.679Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | trans=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBDeviceRegister | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Looking for device with filter [{"id":"sensor03"}]. | comp=IoTAgent
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
time=2018-09-21T09:59:32.717Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | trans=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | op=IOTAUL.IoTUtils | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=MEASURES-001: Couldn't find device data for APIKey [TEF] and DeviceId[sensor03] | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-09-21T09:59:32.717Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | trans=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | op=IOTAUL.Common.Binding | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=MEASURES-005: Error before processing device measures [/TEF/sensor03/attrs] | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-09-21T10:09:51.484Z | lvl=DEBUG | corr=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | trans=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.MongoDBDeviceRegister | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Looking for device with filter [{"id":"sensor03"}]. | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-09-21T10:09:51.504Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | trans=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | op=IOTAUL.IoTUtils | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=MEASURES-001: Couldn't find device data for APIKey [TEF] and DeviceId[sensor03] | comp=IoTAgent
time=2018-09-21T10:09:51.509Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | trans=dbbcd94d-50fc-4062-a05b-bccfa76c52c8 | op=IOTAUL.Common.Binding | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=MEASURES-005: Error before processing device measures [/TEF/sensor03/attrs] | comp=IoTAgent
```

**Show data from MongoDB**

```
    root@727724bdd3d9:/# mongo --shell
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.21
connecting to: test
type "help" for help
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
> show dbs
iotagentul  0.000GB
local       0.000GB
orion       0.000GB
```

It seems to me that you have something wrong about your config set up. Please provide us all the points before comment and for a nice follow up, could you open it in the Github site ? [IotAgent-UL](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul) Take up there

Thanks,

Fernando Méndez - Research Junior Software Engineer